# Disable Client Authentication for python HTTPS requests

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, https, tls1.2

Currently my client side HTTPS request code looks like this:

```py
resp = requests.post(endpoint_predict_v100, files={'image': open(file_path, 'rb')}, verify=client_auth,
                         cert=(client_cert_path, client_secret_path))
```

This is an HTTPS request, the server root CA is `client_auth` and the client certificate and key are `client_cert_path` and `client_secret_path`.

because my server code is deployed and I cannot change much on that side, I am wondering if I can do the following on the client side:

1. enable server authentication only when the server root CA is provided by the client
2. enable client authentication only when the client cert and key are provided by the client.

I have found out that I am able to do the first thing, "enable server authentication only when the server root CA is provided by the client", by passing `verify=False` if the server root CA is not presented on the client side., referring to the [Python requests docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification). However, when I try to remove the `cert=(client_cert_path, client_secret_path)`, the request will fail, throwing this error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] tlsv13 alert certificate required (_ssl.c:2570)
```

It seems that this error is suggesting I must pass in the client cert and key to make the server accept my request. but is there a way to disable client authentication on the client side, when the client cert and key are not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ssl.SSLError: [SSL] tlsv13 alert certificate required (_ssl.c:2570)
> ```
>
> ... is there a way to disable client authentication on the client side, when the client cert and key are not present?

The alert you get is because **the server** is requiring the client certificate. Since it is required by the server it is not sufficient to change some client side behavior only. This is similar to a server requesting authentication by password - this cannot be simply skipped in the client too.

With many servers there is a way to have client certificates optional, i.e. request a client certificate but don't insist that one is sent. How to do this with your specific server and if it is supported by your server at all is unknown though.